# The requested resource (/examples/servlets/) is not available

Tags: tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7.When i started it and tried http://localhost:8080/ on browser,i got
the homepage.However i am not able to navigate to "server examples " which will complete
the proper working of it.Any specific reasons?

Answer (score 0):

A direct link to the examples is: http://localhost:8080/examples/

Also, you may try going into the manager, which should have details about what webapps are running (including if the examples are): http://localhost:8080/manager/

I don't know if you've checked into this or if the manager might have more information for you. Restarting the examples application can't hurt, also restarting tomcat can't hurt. You can also check the log files, as they would have any errors that the server caught. More information about the specifics of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Its working.There was a problem in the web.xml file.When i went through it properly i got where the mistake was in the xml file.